# Equitable sequencing for 3 or more parties

Tags: sequences-and-series, game-theory

If you have two parties selecting objects then it is possible to sequence the selection of objects fairly by using the Thue-Morse sequence.  However is there an equivalent solution for more than a pair?

Comment: Thue-Morse is not necessarily best.  Suppose you have eight things to divide and one is much more valuable than the rest.  The most equitable division is to give that one to one person and all the rest to the other.  If it is necessary to give them each four items, the second person should get the next four choices after the first to get the most even split.  Even if the values are "random" is giving one person $1,4,6,7$ better than $1,4,5,8$?

Comment: I am aware of this.  The hidden assumption is that both parties are have the same total number of selections.  For example in a MTG rotisserie draft.

Comment: But even so, it could be fairer to give one person choices $2,3,4,5$ than $2,3,5,8$ if the first choice is much better than the rest. Say we are picking piles of money off the table and the piles are $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,20$  The most even split is $1,2,3,20$ vs $4,5,6,7$

Comment: I think the analog for more than a pair of agents is probably what is often called a *snake draft.* But there could be no result that this is the *fairest* way of doing it without very strong assumptions on preferences and a concrete definition of fairness (several exist). Also note that drafts (whatever the ordering) may lead to Pareto inefficient outcomes (in the presence of either uncertainty, complementarities, or both). In fact, for general preferences, it has been proven that the only mechanisms that guarantee Pareto efficient outcomes are sequential/serial dictatorships.

Comment: If this interests you, let me know and I can make it into a more comprehensive answer with the references. I'm going to hold off in the mean time as its not clear to me that this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Shane it does.  The inspiration for this comes from my perception that the snake draft could be improved on.